# The procedure entry point iswalnum could not be located in the dynamic link library msys-1.0 dll

Tags: git, heroku, sh

When trying to use the command `git pull heroku master` I get the following error code pop up

```
sh.exe- Entry Point Not Found
```

`The procedure entry point iswalnum could not be located in the dynamic link library msys-1.0 dll`

I'm trying to fix an issue with heroku that won't allow me to `git push heroku master`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I couldn't fix the error code, but I did fix the `git push heroku master issue`

I used `git push --force heroku master` and it force pushed to heroku fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I had installed Git for Windows previously and then uninstalled it.

Make sure that in SourceTree options, you select "Use embedded Git" and not "Use system Git" and then update embedded Git using the provided button. Make sure it succeeded (that no error message popped up while updating the embedded Git).

Restart SourceTree and it should work.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu, why do i even have a system git, im quite happy with it bundled inside sourcetree.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

I couldn't fix the error code, but I did fix the git push heroku master issue I used git push --force heroku master and it force pushed to heroku fine.

Comment: i have same issue, i dont understand. How you fixed that ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by uninstalling, and then [reinstalling Railsinstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/).  You may only have to reinstall Git, but I did everything.